# chrome mobile; navigation.geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, w3c-geolocation

```js
function initGeolocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            maximumAge: 15000,
            timeout: 30000
        };
    }
}
```

This works in desktop chrome, safari, iOS etc; but fails in android chrome browser. Any ideas on how to make this work?

EDIT: I also tried the below and still fails

```js
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fail, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 30000,
    timeout: 27000
});
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, what I found was that I had to change my settings on the OS for location services. I had it set to never, so it wouldn't even prompt me for the services.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Android Location Services are enabled on your device.  Here is a way to check with javascript:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  console.log("geolocation is available");
} else {
  console.log("geolocation IS NOT available");
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: I 'enabled' location services on the device myself; it also prompts to 'allow/deny' to share location when I access the page. So I assume its working.